# How to add custom notification channel in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have an Issue with getting a laravel custom notification channel to work. I have the following git to implement:

[laravel-notification-channels/webhook](https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/webhook)

When I install it as per instructions, create a new notofication, call this notification on my route I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException in Manager.php line 90: Driver [NotificationChannels\Webhook\WebhookChannel] not supported.
```

I noticed that some packeges are registering as Service providers, this one does not however.

What it the problem here please? What Am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved - looks like it was Namespace related.

use NotificationChannels\Webhook\WebhookChannel;
use NotificationChannels\Webhook\WebhookMessage;